# Как сделать блок неподвижным при прокрутке страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать серый блок `Your portfolios` неподвижным при прокрутке страницы?

```css
ody {
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sidebar {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}

.sidebar__list {
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar__item {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.sidebar__square {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 300px;

  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #44519e;
}

.sidebar__number {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #ffffff;

  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;

  text-align: center;
}

.sidebar__icon path {
  stroke: #adb5ca;
}

.sidebar__icon--active path {
  stroke: #54c5eb;
}

.sidebar__photo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;

  width: 60px;
  height: 65px;
  padding-left: 55px;

  background: url(img/avatar.jpg) no-repeat center;
}

.portfolios {
  width: 220px;
  margin-right: 35px;

  background-color: #f1f1f9;
}

.portfolios__title {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #191f5d;

  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 80px;
  padding: 0;

  text-align: center;
}

.portfolios__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;
}

.portfolios__item {
  position: relative;

  min-height: 85px;

  text-align: center;
}

.portfolios__item::before {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;

  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  background: url("img/file.svg") no-repeat;
}

.portfolios__item--active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.portfolios__link {
  display: block;

  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #191f5d;

  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 35px;

  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.page-header {
  display: flex;
}

.page-header__list {
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
  height: 90px;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 150px;

  list-style: none;
  background-color: #f7f7fa;
}

.page-header__item {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.page-header__link--hands {
  position: relative;
}

.page-header__square {
  display: block;
  width: 42px;
  height: 40px;

  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;

  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #dc045c;
}

.page-header__square::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 8px;

  background: url("img/clapping-hands.svg") no-repeat;
}

.page-header__title-container {
  margin-right: 300px;
}

.page-header__subtitle {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 0;

  font-size: 15px;
  color: #a7b0c2;
}

.page-header__title {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  font-size: 36px;
  color: #191f5d;
}

.page-header__search path {
  stroke: #223975;
}

.page-header__group path {
  fill: #223975;
}

.page-header__hands path {
  fill: #ffffff;
}

.graphs__list {
  display: flex;
  margin: 60px 70px 50px 0;
  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;
}

.graphs__item {
  width: 200px;
  min-height: 140px;
  margin-right: 25px;

  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
}

.graphs__title {
  position: relative;

  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #262d73;

  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  padding: 0;
}

.graphs__title--left::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -50px;

  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  background: url("img/twitter.svg") no-repeat;
}

.graphs__item--right::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  left: -50px;

  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;

  background: url("img/bookmark.svg") no-repeat;
}

.graphs__subtitle {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #a7b0c2;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding: 0;
}

.benchmark {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

.benchmark__title {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #191f5d;

  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  padding: 0;
}

.benchmark__list {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;
}

.benchmark__link {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #191f5d;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.benchmark__item {
  margin-right: 18px;
}

.benchmark__logo {
  position: relative;

  width: 37px;
  height: 37px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;

  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
}

.benchmark__logo::before {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;

  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.benchmark__logo--fb::before {
  background: url("img/fb.svg") no-repeat;
}

.benchmark__logo--amzn::before {
  background: url("img/amazon.svg") no-repeat;
}

.benchmark__logo--msft::before {
  background: url("img/msft.svg") no-repeat;
}

.benchmark__logo--wmt::before {
  background: url("img/plus.svg") no-repeat;
}

.benchmark__logo--pg::before {
  background: url("img/document.svg") no-repeat;
}

.benchmark__logo--ibm::before {
  background: url("img/ibm.svg") no-repeat;
}

.benchmark__logo--bac::before {
  background: url("img/home.svg") no-repeat;
}

.benchmark__logo--mcd::before {
  background: url("img/mcdonalds.svg") no-repeat;
}

.benchmark__icon {
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.statistic {
  display: flex;
}

.statistic__top,
.statistic__worst {
  margin-right: 60px;
}

.statistic__list {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  list-style: none;
}

.statistic__top,
.statistic__worst {
  width: 250px;
}

.statistic__title {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #191f5d;
}

.statistic__item {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.statistic__wrapper__text {
  width: 110px;
  margin-right: 40px;
}

.statistic__top-text {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #191f5d;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;

  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.statistic__bottom-text,
.statistic__bottom-percent {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #a7b0c2;

  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.statistic__bottom-percent {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.statistic__logo {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.statistic__logo::before {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;

  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}

.statistic__logo--apple::before {
  background: url("img/apple-logo.svg") no-repeat;
}

.statistic__logo--issuu::before {
  background: url("img/issuu.svg") no-repeat;
}

.statistic__logo--lg::before {
  background: url("img/onedrive.svg") no-repeat;
}

.statistic__logo--intel::before {
  background: url("img/intel.svg") no-repeat;
}

.statistic__logo--yahoo::before {
  background: url("img/yahoo.svg") no-repeat;
}

.statistic__logo--google::before {
  background: url("img/yahoo.svg") no-repeat;
}

.statistic__logo--google::before {
  background: url("img/google.svg") no-repeat;
}

.statistic__details--list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 250px;
}

.statistic__details-item {
  width: 67px;
  margin-right: 21px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.statistic__details-item--last {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.statistic__details-text,
.statistic__details-figures {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.statistic__details-text {
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #a0a8be;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.statistic__details-figures {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #212663;
}

.statistic__details--title {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.statistic__details--title::after {
  content: "";

  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;

  display: block;
  width: 25px;
  height: 2px;

  background-color: #d9e1f9;
}

.crisper {
  display: flex;
}

.schedule__title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #191f5d;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <section class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar__square">
        <p class="sidebar__number">2</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar__list">
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <a class="sidebar__link" href="#">
            <svg class="sidebar__icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25" width="25" viewBox="0 0 41 41"><defs><clipPath id="a" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M0 31h31V0H0z"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 41.333)"><path d="M15.5 29.5v-14h14M15.5 15.5L5.184 5.921" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/><path d="M15.5 29.5c7.732 0 14-6.268 14-14s-6.268-14-14-14-14 6.268-14 14 6.268 14 14 14z" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></g></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <a class="sidebar__link" href="#">
            <svg class="sidebar__icon sidebar__icon--active" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25" width="27" viewBox="0 0 40 42.667"><defs><clipPath id="a" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M0 30h32V0H0z"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 40)"><path d="M24.5 22.5v3h-12l-3 3h-8v-27h23l6 18h-23l-6-18" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></g></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <a class="sidebar__link" href="#">
            <svg class="sidebar__icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="26" viewBox="0 0 39.507 41.333"><defs><clipPath id="a" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M0 29.63h31V0H0z"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 39.507)"><path d="M15.5 28.13l4.326-8.766 9.674-1.406-7-6.823L24.152 1.5 15.5 6.049l-8.652-4.55L8.5 11.136l-7 6.823 9.674 1.406z" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></g></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="sidebar__photo"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="portfolios">
      <h2 class="portfolios__title">Your portfolios</h2>
      <ul class="portfolios__list">
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">Finance inst.</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item portfolios__item--active">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">Strong</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">Rising stars</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">High risks</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">Tech stars</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">MISC</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="page-header">
        <div class="page-header__title-container">
          <h3 class="page-header__subtitle">Strong</h3>
          <h1 class="page-header__title">Overview</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="page-header__list">
          <li class="page-header__item">
            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">
              <svg class="page-header__search" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="21.333" width="21.333"><defs><clipPath id="a" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M0 16h16V0H0z"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 21.333)"><path d="M7 15A6 6 0 007 3a6 6 0 000 12zM15 1l-3.758 3.758" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></g></svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-header__item">
            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">
              <svg class="page-header__group" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
                  <g class="nc-icon-wrapper" fill="#111111">
                      <path d="M32 22c3.31 0 5.98-2.69 5.98-6s-2.67-6-5.98-6c-3.31 0-6 2.69-6 6s2.69 6 6 6zm-16 0c3.31 0 5.98-2.69 5.98-6s-2.67-6-5.98-6c-3.31 0-6 2.69-6 6s2.69 6 6 6zm0 4c-4.67 0-14 2.34-14 7v5h28v-5c0-4.66-9.33-7-14-7zm16 0c-.58 0-1.23.04-1.93.11C32.39 27.78 34 30.03 34 33v5h12v-5c0-4.66-9.33-7-14-7z"></path>
                  </g>
              </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-header__item">
            <a class="page-header__link page-header__link--hands" href="#">
              <div class="page-header__square"></div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <main class="page-main">
        <div class="crisper">
          <div class="page-main__crisper">
            <section class="graphs">
              <ul class="graphs__list">
                <li class="graphs__item">
                  <p class="graphs__title graphs__title--left">Twitter Inc</p>
                  <p class="graphs__subtitle">NASDAQ</p>
                </li>
                <li class="graphs__item">
                  <p class="graphs__title graphs__item--right">LG Inc</p>
                  <p class="graphs__subtitle">KRX</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="benchmark">
              <p class="benchmark__title">Benchmark</p>
              <ul class="benchmark__list">
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--fb"></div>
                    <div>fb</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--amzn"></div>
                    <div>amzn</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--msft"></div>
                    <div>msft</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--wmt"></div>
                    <div>wmt</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--pg"></div>
                    <div>pg</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--ibm"></div>
                    <div>ibm</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--bac"></div>
                    <div>bac</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--mcd"></div>
                    <div>mcd</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </section>
          </div>
          <section class="schedule">
            <p class="schedule__title">yhoo</p>
            <div class="schedule__diagram"></div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <section class="statistic">
          <div class="statistic__top">
            <h4 class="statistic__title">Top 3 stocks</h4>
            <ul class="statistic__list">
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--apple"></div>
                  <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                    <p class="statistic__top-text">appl</p>
                    <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Apple - NASDAQ</p>
                  </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">+12.5%</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--issuu"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">mat</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Mattle - NASDAQ</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">+10.8%</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--lg"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">lgcif</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">LG Corporation</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">+10.0%</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="statistic__worst">
            <h4 class="statistic__title">Worst 3 stocks</h4>
            <ul class="statistic__list">
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--intel"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">intc</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Intel - NASDAQ</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">-9.5%</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--yahoo"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">yhoo</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Yahoo - NASDAQ</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">-2.9%</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--google"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">googl</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Alphabet - NASDAQ</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">-0.2%</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="statistic__details">
            <h4 class="statistic__details--title statistic__title">Stock details</h4>
            <ul class="statistic__details--list statistic__list">
              <li class="statistic__details-item">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">open</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">7,200</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">high</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">9,500</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item statistic__details-item--last">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">52wk high</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">1,9007</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">prev close</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">7,120</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">low</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">1,200</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item statistic__details-item--last">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">52wk low</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">2,009</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
  .ody {
      font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
      margin: 0;
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      width: 1200px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .sidebar {
      position: relative;
      width: 60px;
    }

    .sidebar__list {
      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 20px;
      padding: 0;

      list-style: none;
    }

    .sidebar__item {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .sidebar__square {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;

      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 300px;

      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #44519e;
    }

    .sidebar__number {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #ffffff;

      margin: 0;
      margin-top: 10px;
      padding: 0;
      padding-top: 10px;

      text-align: center;
    }

    .sidebar__icon path {
      stroke: #adb5ca;
    }

    .sidebar__icon--active path {
      stroke: #54c5eb;
    }

    .sidebar__photo {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      z-index: -1;

      width: 60px;
      height: 65px;
      padding-left: 55px;

      background: url(img/avatar.jpg) no-repeat center;
    }

    .portfolios {
      width: 220px;
      margin-right: 35px;

      background-color: #f1f1f9;
    }

    .portfolios__title {
      font-size: 20px;
      color: #191f5d;

      margin: 0;
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-bottom: 80px;
      padding: 0;

      text-align: center;
    }

    .portfolios__list {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      list-style: none;
    }

    .portfolios__item {
      position: relative;

      min-height: 85px;

      text-align: center;
    }

    .portfolios__item::before {
      content: "";

      position: absolute;
      top: 30px;
      left: 30px;

      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;

      background: url("img/file.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .portfolios__item--active {
      background-color: #ffffff;
    }

    .portfolios__link {
      display: block;

      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #191f5d;

      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding: 0;
      padding-top: 35px;

      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .page-header {
      display: flex;
    }

    .page-header__list {
      display: flex;
      width: 300px;
      height: 90px;

      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      padding-left: 150px;

      list-style: none;
      background-color: #f7f7fa;
    }

    .page-header__item {
      margin-top: 40px;
      margin-right: 50px;
    }

    .page-header__link--hands {
      position: relative;
    }

    .page-header__square {
      display: block;
      width: 42px;
      height: 40px;

      position: absolute;
      top: -10px;

      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #dc045c;
    }

    .page-header__square::before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;

      position: absolute;
      top: 8px;
      left: 8px;

      background: url("img/clapping-hands.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .page-header__title-container {
      margin-right: 300px;
    }

    .page-header__subtitle {
      margin: 0;
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;
      padding: 0;

      font-size: 15px;
      color: #a7b0c2;
    }

    .page-header__title {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      font-size: 36px;
      color: #191f5d;
    }

    .page-header__search path {
      stroke: #223975;
    }

    .page-header__group path {
      fill: #223975;
    }

    .page-header__hands path {
      fill: #ffffff;
    }

    .graphs__list {
      display: flex;
      margin: 60px 70px 50px 0;
      padding: 0;

      list-style: none;
    }

    .graphs__item {
      width: 200px;
      min-height: 140px;
      margin-right: 25px;

      background-color: #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
    }

    .graphs__title {
      position: relative;

      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #262d73;

      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 70px;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .graphs__title--left::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -2px;
      left: -50px;

      display: block;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;

      background: url("img/twitter.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .graphs__item--right::before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -2px;
      left: -50px;

      display: block;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;

      background: url("img/bookmark.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .graphs__subtitle {
      font-size: 12px;
      color: #a7b0c2;
      text-transform: uppercase;

      margin: 0;
      margin-left: 70px;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .benchmark {
      margin-bottom: 70px;
    }

    .benchmark__title {
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #191f5d;

      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 40px;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .benchmark__list {
      display: flex;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      list-style: none;
    }

    .benchmark__link {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #191f5d;
      text-align: center;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .benchmark__item {
      margin-right: 18px;
    }

    .benchmark__logo {
      position: relative;

      width: 37px;
      height: 37px;
      margin-bottom: 20px;

      background-color: #ffffff;
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(247, 247, 247, 1);
    }

    .benchmark__logo::before {
      content: "";

      position: absolute;
      top: 5px;
      left: 5px;

      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    .benchmark__logo--fb::before {
      background: url("img/fb.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .benchmark__logo--amzn::before {
      background: url("img/amazon.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .benchmark__logo--msft::before {
      background: url("img/msft.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .benchmark__logo--wmt::before {
      background: url("img/plus.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .benchmark__logo--pg::before {
      background: url("img/document.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .benchmark__logo--ibm::before {
      background: url("img/ibm.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .benchmark__logo--bac::before {
      background: url("img/home.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .benchmark__logo--mcd::before {
      background: url("img/mcdonalds.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .benchmark__icon {
      margin-top: 3px;
    }

    .statistic {
      display: flex;
    }

    .statistic__top,
    .statistic__worst {
      margin-right: 60px;
    }

    .statistic__list {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      list-style: none;
    }

    .statistic__top,
    .statistic__worst {
      width: 250px;
    }

    .statistic__title {
      font-size: 16px;
      color: #191f5d;
    }

    .statistic__item {
      display: flex;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .statistic__wrapper__text {
      width: 110px;
      margin-right: 40px;
    }

    .statistic__top-text {
      font-size: 15px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #191f5d;

      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;

      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    .statistic__bottom-text,
    .statistic__bottom-percent {
      font-size: 12px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #a7b0c2;

      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .statistic__bottom-percent {
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .statistic__logo {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .statistic__logo::before {
      content: "";

      position: absolute;

      display: block;
      width: 30px;
      height: 30px;
    }

    .statistic__logo--apple::before {
      background: url("img/apple-logo.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .statistic__logo--issuu::before {
      background: url("img/issuu.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .statistic__logo--lg::before {
      background: url("img/onedrive.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .statistic__logo--intel::before {
      background: url("img/intel.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .statistic__logo--yahoo::before {
      background: url("img/yahoo.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .statistic__logo--google::before {
      background: url("img/yahoo.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .statistic__logo--google::before {
      background: url("img/google.svg") no-repeat;
    }

    .statistic__details--list {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      width: 250px;
    }

    .statistic__details-item {
      width: 67px;
      margin-right: 21px;
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }

    .statistic__details-item--last {
      margin-right: 0;
    }

    .statistic__details-text,
    .statistic__details-figures {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    .statistic__details-text {
      font-size: 11px;
      color: #a0a8be;
      text-transform: uppercase;

      margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .statistic__details-figures {
      font-size: 13px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: #212663;
    }

    .statistic__details--title {
      position: relative;
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }

    .statistic__details--title::after {
      content: "";

      position: absolute;
      top: 40px;

      display: block;
      width: 25px;
      height: 2px;

      background-color: #d9e1f9;
    }

    .crisper {
      display: flex;
    }

    .schedule__title {
      font-size: 38px;
      color: #191f5d;
      text-transform: uppercase;
    }

.page-header{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: red;
}

body{
  height: 1500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <section class="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar__square">
        <p class="sidebar__number">2</p>
      </div>
      <ul class="sidebar__list">
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <a class="sidebar__link" href="#">
            <svg class="sidebar__icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25" width="25" viewBox="0 0 41 41"><defs><clipPath id="a" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M0 31h31V0H0z"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 41.333)"><path d="M15.5 29.5v-14h14M15.5 15.5L5.184 5.921" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/><path d="M15.5 29.5c7.732 0 14-6.268 14-14s-6.268-14-14-14-14 6.268-14 14 6.268 14 14 14z" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></g></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <a class="sidebar__link" href="#">
            <svg class="sidebar__icon sidebar__icon--active" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="25" width="27" viewBox="0 0 40 42.667"><defs><clipPath id="a" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M0 30h32V0H0z"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 40)"><path d="M24.5 22.5v3h-12l-3 3h-8v-27h23l6 18h-23l-6-18" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></g></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="sidebar__item">
          <a class="sidebar__link" href="#">
            <svg class="sidebar__icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="24" width="26" viewBox="0 0 39.507 41.333"><defs><clipPath id="a" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M0 29.63h31V0H0z"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 39.507)"><path d="M15.5 28.13l4.326-8.766 9.674-1.406-7-6.823L24.152 1.5 15.5 6.049l-8.652-4.55L8.5 11.136l-7 6.823 9.674 1.406z" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></g></svg>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="sidebar__photo"></div>
    </section>
    <section class="portfolios">
      <h2 class="portfolios__title">Your portfolios</h2>
      <ul class="portfolios__list">
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">Finance inst.</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item portfolios__item--active">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">Strong</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">Rising stars</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">High risks</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">Tech stars</a>
        </li>
        <li class="portfolios__item">
          <a class="portfolios__link" href="#">MISC</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
    <div class="container">
      <header class="page-header">
        <div class="page-header__title-container">
          <h3 class="page-header__subtitle">Strong</h3>
          <h1 class="page-header__title">Overview</h1>
        </div>
        <ul class="page-header__list">
          <li class="page-header__item">
            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">
              <svg class="page-header__search" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="21.333" width="21.333"><defs><clipPath id="a" clipPathUnits="userSpaceOnUse"><path d="M0 16h16V0H0z"/></clipPath></defs><g clip-path="url(#a)" transform="matrix(1.33333 0 0 -1.33333 0 21.333)"><path d="M7 15A6 6 0 007 3a6 6 0 000 12zM15 1l-3.758 3.758" fill="none" stroke="#111" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10"/></g></svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-header__item">
            <a class="page-header__link" href="#">
              <svg class="page-header__group" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="28" height="28" viewBox="0 0 48 48">
                  <g class="nc-icon-wrapper" fill="#111111">
                      <path d="M32 22c3.31 0 5.98-2.69 5.98-6s-2.67-6-5.98-6c-3.31 0-6 2.69-6 6s2.69 6 6 6zm-16 0c3.31 0 5.98-2.69 5.98-6s-2.67-6-5.98-6c-3.31 0-6 2.69-6 6s2.69 6 6 6zm0 4c-4.67 0-14 2.34-14 7v5h28v-5c0-4.66-9.33-7-14-7zm16 0c-.58 0-1.23.04-1.93.11C32.39 27.78 34 30.03 34 33v5h12v-5c0-4.66-9.33-7-14-7z"></path>
                  </g>
              </svg>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="page-header__item">
            <a class="page-header__link page-header__link--hands" href="#">
              <div class="page-header__square"></div>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </header>
      <main class="page-main">
        <div class="crisper">
          <div class="page-main__crisper">
            <section class="graphs">
              <ul class="graphs__list">
                <li class="graphs__item">
                  <p class="graphs__title graphs__title--left">Twitter Inc</p>
                  <p class="graphs__subtitle">NASDAQ</p>
                </li>
                <li class="graphs__item">
                  <p class="graphs__title graphs__item--right">LG Inc</p>
                  <p class="graphs__subtitle">KRX</p>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </section>
            <section class="benchmark">
              <p class="benchmark__title">Benchmark</p>
              <ul class="benchmark__list">
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--fb"></div>
                    <div>fb</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--amzn"></div>
                    <div>amzn</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--msft"></div>
                    <div>msft</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--wmt"></div>
                    <div>wmt</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--pg"></div>
                    <div>pg</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--ibm"></div>
                    <div>ibm</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--bac"></div>
                    <div>bac</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
                <li class="benchmark__item">
                  <a class="benchmark__link" href="#">
                    <div class="benchmark__logo benchmark__logo--mcd"></div>
                    <div>mcd</div>
                  </a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </section>
          </div>
          <section class="schedule">
            <p class="schedule__title">yhoo</p>
            <div class="schedule__diagram"></div>
          </section>
        </div>
        <section class="statistic">
          <div class="statistic__top">
            <h4 class="statistic__title">Top 3 stocks</h4>
            <ul class="statistic__list">
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--apple"></div>
                  <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                    <p class="statistic__top-text">appl</p>
                    <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Apple - NASDAQ</p>
                  </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">+12.5%</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--issuu"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">mat</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Mattle - NASDAQ</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">+10.8%</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--lg"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">lgcif</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">LG Corporation</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">+10.0%</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="statistic__worst">
            <h4 class="statistic__title">Worst 3 stocks</h4>
            <ul class="statistic__list">
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--intel"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">intc</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Intel - NASDAQ</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">-9.5%</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--yahoo"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">yhoo</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Yahoo - NASDAQ</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">-2.9%</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__item">
                <div class="statistic__logo statistic__logo--google"></div>
                <div class="statistic__wrapper__text">
                  <p class="statistic__top-text">googl</p>
                  <p class="statistic__bottom-text">Alphabet - NASDAQ</p>
                </div>
                <p class="statistic__bottom-percent">-0.2%</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="statistic__details">
            <h4 class="statistic__details--title statistic__title">Stock details</h4>
            <ul class="statistic__details--list statistic__list">
              <li class="statistic__details-item">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">open</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">7,200</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">high</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">9,500</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item statistic__details-item--last">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">52wk high</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">1,9007</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">prev close</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">7,120</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">low</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">1,200</p>
              </li>
              <li class="statistic__details-item statistic__details-item--last">
                <p class="statistic__details-text">52wk low</p>
                <p class="statistic__details-figures">2,009</p>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </section>
      </main>
    </div>
  </div>
```

1. **.page-header** добавил  **position: fixed;**
2. **Для демонстрации** классу **.page-header** добавил  **background-color: red;** и **body height: 1500px;**