# Отцентровка изображения во всплывающем окне

Tags: javascript, css, popup

Как сделать, чтобы картинка отображалась всегда по центру, на каком уровне скролла страницы бы я ни был?

Когда пользователь кликает по изображению, оно отображается на верху веб-страницы, даже если превью в самом низу.

Заранее извиняюсь, что ссылка на сайт, вместо кода: http://test.srv160751.hoster-test.ru/

Comment: Brown Fox https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1044873/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d1%8b/1044894#1044894

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изображение при открытии "заворачивается" в класс `.uk-open`. Позиционирование изображения - в классе `.uk-slidenav-position`. Далее я основываюсь исключительно на коде из "консоли разработчика, в коде ниже отражены только изменения, которые необходимо внести в код:

```
<div class="uk-modal uk-open" style="position: fixed; ...">
<div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-lightbox uk-slidenav-position" style="top: 50vh;">
```

`top: 50vh` отвечает за позиционирование элемента по вертикали. Отступ равен 50% высоты viewport.
И на будущее: не пользуйтесь `<div style="...">`. Впоследствии неудобно будет изменять стили элементов, так как браузеры ставят б**о**льший приоритет стилям, которые прописаны в div. Это означет, что при конфликте таблицы стилей и style внутри тега (то бишь):

```
.uk-open { position: fixed; }
```

и:

```
<div class="uk-open" style="position: relative">...</div
```

Блок будет отображен со стилем `position: relative`.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тебе пример как это можно сделать, а без кода я не знаю как там у тебя.

```js
let box = document.querySelectorAll('.box')
for (let i = 0; i < box.length; i++) {
  box[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.classList.add('enother-class')
  })
}
```

```css
.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.enother-class {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```